# Checking Phase sequence in a 3Ph. supply with uC

Tags: three-phase

I am measuring the phase to neutral voltage in a 3 Ph. system. The ADC measures each of the phases in turn.
All the voltages are scaled down and offset to center around 2.5V. The voltages are averaged at 500uS
intervals and displayed. This works satisfactorily.
Is there any fast algorithm to check the sequence of the phases in a setup like this.
I can take an arbitrary phase connection as the 'R' phase and get the other phase voltages with an offset of about 25uS(due to the ADC sampling rate). I am unable to add any zero crossing detection, so would it be possible to do this in the firmware only ?
I have to do this check only once during power up.
I did get some prompts, but could not find an applicable solution.

*Edits & Clarifications*

1)This is a 50Hz mains sinus system.

2)The algorithm is implemented as follows : There are 6 parameters being measured viz. Rin,Yin,Bin; Rout,Yout,Bout ; RIout,YIout,BIout. In one measurement cycle all the parameters are measured in turn, with an interval of 25uS (ADC sampling rate). This cycle is repeated every 500uS, after which the average value of each parameter is computed and converted to RMS.

3. The measurement of the Voltages , are P-N.

TIA

Comment: I assume this is either 50 or 60 Hz, right? Are you getting two samples per ms on each phase? If so I think you can just do software based zero crossing detection. It will be close enough for determining phase sequence. Or software based peak detection (take your pick).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Wait until phase A is near peak. Then see whether B or C goes positive first.*

*Pseudo code*

```
aMax = 0;                        // Peak voltage on phase A
t0 = millis();                   // Start time.

while((millis() - t0) < 100){    // Monitor a few cycles.
  if (Ain0 > aMax){
    aMax = Ain0;                 // Peak voltage phase A.
  }
}
while(Ain0 < aMax * 0.8)         // Wait until A is near peak.
}
while(1 = 1){     // Now wait see which phase comes up first.
  if(Ain1 > aMax * 0.8){         // Phase B.
    dir = 1;                     // ABC sequence.
    break;
  }
  if(Ain2 > aMax * 0.8){         // Phase C.
    dir = 0;                     // ACB sequence.
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Super , Thanks much. Will code and revert !!

Comment: Your post doesn't make clear whether you're measuring P-N or P-P. You might edit to clarify. It might affect my answer.

Comment: I am measuring P-N.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Goertzel algorithm to compute the FFT for the frequency bin closest to the fundamental. Apply this algorithm for each phase (A, B and C).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm

You will now have a rough estimate of each phase's phasor. Now you can use the Fortescue transform to evaluate the positive, negative and zero sequences.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetrical_components

If the negative sequence or zero sequence is greater than the positive sequence, you know there's something wrong in your wiring, connections, etc.

Comment: Strike "zero sequence" as that portion of your statement is incorrect.  But, you are spot on in regards to negative sequence.  Nice.  Rolling phases produces 100% negative sequence, 0% positive sequence, and 0% zero sequence (assuming perfectly balanced phasors).

Comment: I'm not sure why? Or you mean that the zero sequence can never be greater than the positive sequence even if the wiring is somehow faulty?

Comment: No, if the phasors are balanced (e.g. 100∠0, 100∠120, 100∠-120) then the zero sequence will be zero.  Doesn't matter if the phasors are ABC or ACB rotation.

Comment: Also, his 25µS delay between sampling each voltage adds about 1/2 degree in a 60Hz system (not enough to mess up either yours or Transistors approaches).  The time for 360 electrical degrees of 60Hz is 16.67mS, so (360°/16.67mS)*25µS = 0.54° error.  But, larger delay between sampling each phase voltage will increase phase angle error.

Comment: True, but if a one phase is not properly connected, the zero sequence will be significant. 
And not sure if the sampling is multiplexed or not. We'd have to ask the OP.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly connected"?  If you mean 1 phase is missing or connected with reverse polarity then yes, there will be significant zero sequence.  But, if you mean that 2 phases are simply rolled in position then no, there won't be any significant zero sequence.  Swapping 2 phases in this equation doesn't change the result: \$3V_0=V_A+V_B+V_C\$.

Comment: Broken measurement wire for example

Comment: Thanks for the answers ! I will try Transistor's approach first , since it is simpler to understand & implement ( for me i.e.) . I would have to so the phase sequence only once at power on , so I will do the phase seq. check routine on the Vin channels at start up and disable the remaining six channels.